How to Upsert Nested Relations in Prisma, using connectOrCreate? connectOrCreate doesn't update deeply nested relation
I'm working on an application using Prisma ORM with a schema that includes Profile, Contact, and SocialMedia models. I need to perform an update operation on a Profile, which should also handle upserting related Contact and SocialMedia entries.
Here’s the schema for the models:

model SocialMedia {
  id         Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  platform   String
  profileUrl String
  username   String
  contact    Contact @relation(fields: [userId], references: [userId])
  userId     Int     @unique
}

model Contact {
  id          Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  email       String?
  socialmedia SocialMedia[]
  profile     Profile       @relation(fields: [userId], references: [userId])
  userId      Int           @unique
}

model Profile {
  contact         Contact[]
  user            User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId          Int       @id @unique
}


Here's the code I'm using to update the Profile, including nested upserts for Contact and SocialMedia:
updateProfile = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const id: number = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
    const p = req.body;
    const c = p.contact;

    const result = await prisma.profile.update({
      include: {
        contact: {
          include: {
            socialmedia: true,
          },
        },
      },
      where: { userId: id },
      data: {
        ...p,
        contact: {
          connectOrCreate: c.map((citem: { socialmedia: [] }) => {
            return {
              where: { id: id },
              create: {
                ...citem,
                socialmedia: {
                  connectOrCreate: citem.socialmedia.map((smitem: object) => {
                    return { where: { id: id }, create: smitem };
                  }),
                },
              },
            };
          }),
        },
      },
    });

    res.status(200).json(result);
});

Result

First connectOrCreate call updates/creates it's part meanwhile second connectOrCreate doesn't.

Question

Why deeply nested connectOrCreate doesn't work?
Is there a better approach to perform nested array upserts with Prisma?

Additional Information:
I’m using Prisma with a relational database (postgre).
